# Would it be correct to assume that inner query ordering will follow into my outer query?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan

Is it spelt out someplace in the documentation that if I do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM foo 
  ORDER BY bar ASC
  LIMIT 1000
)
LIMIT 10
OFFSET 10
```

then the inner query ordering will carry on into the outer query?

Or do I need to repeat the inner query `ORDER BY` in my outer query? This is assuming that we don't have any joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot depend on any ordering unless you have `ORDER BY` in the outer query. The ordering will depend on the execution plan chosen.

In the case of the present query I cannot think of a reasonable execution plan that would *not* preserve the ordering, but who knows what the future will bring for the query optimizer?

I would write a second `ORDER BY`. Sorting 1000 rows is cheap, and you can be certain then.